# Cloud Vision Product Search python API for deleting a product set is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I try to use both COMMAND-LINE and python API to delete a product set. They both return as successful, however, I check product set and find the deleted product set is still there (after 1 week, I can still find this deleted product set in indexing). Any developer can fix this problem?

I delete one product set and I found that the product set is still in Google Product Search. I think this problem can come from this product need delete first.

"Deleting a product set immediately removes the product set from results. However, deleting a product set will not remove individual products in the set, as a product may belong to several different sets. You do not need to wait for the next index for the change to take effect." -- Cloud Vision Product Search documentation

Next, I try to delete every product in this product set and delete this product set again. After 1 week, the product set is still there, but no products in this product set (I use list_products_in_product_set() to check it)

```py
from google.cloud import vision

def delete_product(project_id, location, product_id):
    """Delete the product and all its reference images.
    Args:
        project_id: Id of the project.
        location: A compute region name.
        product_id: Id of the product.
    """
    client = vision.ProductSearchClient()

    # Get the full path of the product.
    product_path = client.product_path(
        project=project_id, location=location, product=product_id)

    # Delete a product.
    client.delete_product(name=product_path)
    print('Product deleted.')
```

```py
from google.cloud import vision

def delete_product_set(project_id, location, product_set_id):
    """Delete a product set.
    Args:
        project_id: Id of the project.
        location: A compute region name.
        product_set_id: Id of the product set.
    """
    client = vision.ProductSearchClient()

    # Get the full path of the product set.
    product_set_path = client.product_set_path(
        project=project_id, location=location,
        product_set=product_set_id)

    # Delete the product set.
    client.delete_product_set(name=product_set_path)
    print('Product set deleted.')
```

I hope the developer can fix this problem as soon as you can.

Comment: I think this product set exit some bugs. I create another product set and delete it. It can be successfully deleted. How to fix those bugs. ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use "from google.cloud import vision_v1p4beta1" to delete the product set.

Don't use "from google.cloud import vision" to delete the product set because you may get some bugs as I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can call get_product_set to verify the ProductSet was deleted instead of list_products_in_product_set.

Comment: I used get_product_set  to confirm whether  ProductSet was deleted or not. Here, when I used "from google.cloud import vision", it will not delete. When I used "from google.cloud import vision_v1p4beta1" it will delete.